# PHP mail() function - which daemon it is tied to in Linux

Tags: php, email

I am working on a production server I inherited, and I do not know whether mail is turned "on" for this server or not.

I'm posting this because I did a search and didn't find these specifics. Questions I've seen focus on the mail() function and not the mail daemon or process on the server.

This should work and return true:

```
echo $result=mail('myemail@me.com','test email','hello Clarice','From: tests@mysite.com');
```

However it echoes nothing.

How do I find if either PHP mail is turned on or off, or if the process on the SERVER is just not turned on?  Thanks.  I am pretty sure mail is not being sent out nor has been ever sent out from this particular service.

Comment: Check in php.ini , did you set the SMTP and smtp_port ?

Comment: yes, I have smtp_port = 25; and also SMTP = localhost

Answer (score 1):

First of all, echo does not print booleans. For that, use `var_dump`.

Secondly, if you want to know if mail has been configured for your server, place this code in an empty php file:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
```

It will print all information about PHP regarding versions, installed extensions and configuration.

Comment: that yields:
sendmail_from = no value
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 
mail.add_x_header = On On
mail.force_extra_parameters = no value no value
mail.log = no value
*but* I don't know if that means that mail is "on"

Comment: There is no such thing as mail being on or off, it's always on, it's just a function in PHP.